# Algebraic structure associated to anti-commutators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Suppose I wanted to describe an algebraic structure analogous to Lie Algebras, but for anticommutators instead of commutators. Then, I write some axioms down like this: An (anti) Lie Algebra is a set $S$ equipped with an operation $\{\cdot, \cdot\}$ such that

- Bilinearity and symmetry : $\{ax+by,z\} = \{z,ax + by\} = a\{x,z\} + b\{y,z\}$
- `Higher order Jacobi identities' :
  $$\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\} + \{\{a,c\},\{b,d\}\} + \{\{a,d\},\{b,c\}\} = \{\{\{a,b\},d\},c\} + \{\{\{a,c\},d\},b\} + \{\{\{b,c\},d\},a\} = \cdots$$

Does this kind of an idea have a name? I want to be able to write down these identities that the anticommutator of linear operators satisfies, that describes anticommutator structures generically. In particular, is it true that any such $S$ that satisfies the above properties has a linear representation, $S \to \text{End}(V)$ (with the traditional anticommutator of linear operators on the right hand side?) Is just the lowest order 'Jacobi identities' needed for this to work? (as in, the one I wrote down above?)

Comment: $A^{-}$ with $[x,y]=x\cdot y-y\cdot x$ of an associative algebra $(A,\cdot)$ is a Lie algebra, and $A^+$ with $\{x,y\}=x\cdot y+y\cdot x$ is a Jordan algebra. This would be my interpretation of "anti-commutator". Is it what you mean?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, Jordan Algebra was the word I was looking for, thanks! Taking any algebra and looking at $\{x,y\} = xy + yx$ you get a product satisfying 'Jordan Identity'; my question in the second paragraph is about the reverse : given anything satisfying the Jordan Identity, does it naturally embed in a regular algebra (equipped with the regular anticommutator?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the word I was looking for is a **Jordan Algebra**, whose multiplication satisfies:
$$x\cdot y = y\cdot x \mathrm{\ (commutativity)}, \quad (x\cdot y)\cdot (x\cdot x) = x\cdot (y\cdot (x\cdot x)) \ \mathrm{(Jordan\ identity)}$$
The 'higher order Jacobi identities' I had initially written in the question are just a more complicated version of the Jordan Identity.

To answer the second part of my question, any associative algebra with product $\circ$ has a Jordan Algebra structure $\cdot$ as well, when you define:
$$x \cdot y = \frac{x \circ y + y \circ x}{2}$$
The factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is, as far as I can tell, just a convention. All such Jordan Algebras that are built from associative algebras are called *special Jordan Algebras*, but there are Jordan Algebras which are not built from this construction, called [*exceptional Jordan Algebras*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_algebra).